# Cannot find vertical error bars in Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I cannot find vertical error bars in Excel chart.  I tried from here:

[image: I tried from here but]

But I got only one horizontal error bar as seen in this picture:

[image: I got only one horizontal error bar as seen in picture]

But I need vertical error bars.

Comment: Maybe the vertical error bars are present, but their lengths are so short, they are hidden behind the markers. If you right click on the chart, you get two pop-ups; one has the controls to format fill and border and a drop-down that lists all of the chart elements. Select the vertical error bars from a series, then Ctrl+1 to open the dialog to format their values.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but see if you can add to vertical error bars to a custom value... check out the source document also:

[image: Vertical Bar Error]

> Source:
>
> https://www.rwu.edu/sites/default/files/downloads/fcas/mns/adding_error_bars_to_excel_graphs.pdf